# Create instance of call with autowire

Tags: java, spring

I have to create a instance of a class, that have autowired elements, for test.

```
public class MyClass extends SomeOtherClass {
    @Autowired
    public MyClass(OtherClass1 one, OtherClass2 two){
        super(one, two)
    }
}
```

How can i in code create instance of this class, with the arguments wired in though spring?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of passing the other elements in as constructor arguments, you Autowire them as properties. Spring will then inject the objects.

```
public class MyClass extends SomeOtherClass {

    @Autowired
    private OtherClass1 one;

    @Autowired
    private OtherClass2 two

    public MyClass(){
        super(one, two)
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Based on http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-auto-wiring-beans-with-autowired-annotation/, adding @Autowired to the constructor is also valid.

If you want to Autowire MyClass, you must annotate it with @Component or a similar annotation such as @Service.

```
@Component
public class MyClass extends SomeOtherClass
```

Then, you can use it in other classes

```
public class ClassThatUsesMyClass {
    @Autowire
    private MyClass myClass;
}
```

Comment: Sorry i should have said that i am not able to change the class

Comment: That should be possible by defining the bean in application-context.xml. Unfortunately, I don't have much experience doing that, but http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html should give you a decent reference of how to start. Specifically, look at the "ref" field of the property annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Your test can be made Spring-aware if you use the [SpringJUnit4ClassRunner](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/junit4/SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.html) to read in your Spring Context to be used in the test. For instance:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"the-config.xml"})
public final class MyClassTests {
    @Autowired   
    private MyClass testee;

    @Test
    public void testSomething() {
        assertThat(testee).doesSomethingExpected();
    }
}
```

Note that you should reuse as much of your production config as possible and not create a parallel Spring Context config that mirrors it.